# Creating Unique User ID

Tags: android, mysql

I am currently using PHPmyadmin to store data in my mySQL database. The android application I am developing requires the user to select some data and this data along with its attributes need to be stored in my mySQL database. I know I have to create a unique table for every user who downloads my application but how do I go about doing this without having access to the program which the user downloads ?

For eg: let us say there are two phones which download my application. I would want to create two tables in my database which the particular phone knows and can access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating one table for every user is a terrible approach. Instead you should create a users table, with a unique ID set to auto_increment, to generate those unique IDs. Then use separate tables to store the data you might need, referencing the user ID from the users table.

It might sound a little confusing, but there are lots of good reads about this on the Internet.

Comment: Chevi, Can you please point me to some good tutorials on this ? I am very new to SQL databases and assigning user IDs and have no clue how to go about it

Comment: After a quick search I found this: http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/support/CreatingAQuickMySQLRelationalDatabase#head-16bb908faaae86a49457a37e8e4cf3989c70ec90 although it might not be easy to follow for a complete newbie

Comment: So  i need to learn how to set up a relational database(im working on that). Okay. But how do i generate this dynamically from android using jdbc.

Comment: sorry if this seems like a  stupid question but the link you posted is for creation of a database in android and not an external database on the web. Also i wanted to know why creating a unique table for every user is a bad idea. When i index the user id with a unique table isnt it as good as creating a unique table for every user.

Comment: I thought you wanted the database in Android. Creating a unique table for every user is bad practice, explaining why is not very easy since it depends on the way their engines work. Creating one user table and an index on user ID doesn't create many tables, you will have only one and the index, which is usually very small, and improves performance a lot

Comment: but what does the index point to .(i thought it pointed to a table).

Comment: You create a table users for example. With `userID|name|...` as columns. Imagine now you want to store pictures uploaded by users, you create a table called pics, with `picID|userID|src`, where picID is the unique ID of a picture, and userID is a **reference** to a certain user from the users table. In the users table, the userID column will be defined as PRIMARY because every row will be unique, and it's the column you will be searching the most. It's hard to explain in a comment, you should experiment and read as much as you can about the subject.

Comment: sorry for asking so many questions but if thats the case then cant we just create as many columns as required along with the userid also as a column and have only one table without any need to index.For example userid|name|no|data|src and have a lot of records. What would be the advantage in referencing the user id to a separate table.

Comment: You could do that, but only if the users are able to upload 1 picture. If you want the uploading more than 1, and you do it your way, you would have duplicate data (user name for example).
The goal is to avoid redundancy when you design your databases

Comment: Fine i get it . Will go through some tutorials on the web. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique user id in php using `uniqid(”, true)` function.